# Multi-dimensional array data type in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to create a 2-D array inside a function, and then use it elsewhere, but I'm stuck everywhere with incompatible pointer types. (I know, similar topics has been discussed, but still can't clearly figure it out from the existing boards.)

So here is the story:

I can pass an array to a function like this (with c99 allowed):

```
int func1(int N, int arr[][N]);
int main()
{
   int N=<something>,M=<something>;
   int array1[N][N];
   func1(N, array1);
}
```

My understanding is, that array1 is effectively a pointer () though i'm unsure of it's type (is it same as `int *p` or else?)

Now, the issue is that I'm trying to create this 2-D array by using a function (which scans the array dimensions to a certain variables, allocates memory for the array, fills it with data, and returns a pointer, to be used in the future), such as:

```
int *input_array(int *size_x,int *size_y)
{
    scanf("%d",size_x); //recieve array dimensions
    scanf("%d",size_y); //recieve array dimensions

    int *arr=malloc((*size_x)*(*size_y)*sizeof(int));
    if(!arr) return 0; //validate allocation success

    for(int i=0; i<(*size_x); i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<(*size_y); j++) {
            scanf("%d",arr[i][j]); //fill input data in to array  <- FAILS
        }
    }
    return arr; //return pointer to the start of arr[][]
}
```

There is compilation failure on the `scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);` line, due to incompatible `arr` type.

So, how can I convert `int *p` to the same type as `int arr[][]` (and what is exactly it's type), so I can reuse it elsewhere in the program? Or maybe I make create the allocation of a different type for this matter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't know the type of arr you should stick to the classic way of allocating arrays. arr is a pointer to int, not a pointer to pointers to int.

Comment: Right, I know how to do it in a simpler way, but it will not be flexible, and also fixing this understanding gap will allow me to code in a more flexible and efficient code. That's the whole point.

Answer (score 2):

This might Help You

```
if (( c = ( int** )malloc( N*sizeof( int* ))) == NULL )
{ /* error */ }

for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
  /* x_i here is the size of given row, need to
   *  multiply by sizeof( int )
   */
  if (( c[i] = ( int* )malloc( x_i )) == NULL )
  { /* error */ }

  /* probably init the row here */
}
```

Comment: So' I basically need to create an array of pointers |_*p_|_*p_|_*p_|_-..._|_*p_| type of which is `int**`, and then each `*p` will be an `int*` pointer to a 1-D array (equal to type of `arr[]`)?

Comment: @smartxchange: No, you do not need to do that, and it is generally a bad idea. It is a method suggested on Stack Overflow and used by students, possibly because it looks neat, but it is generally not used in commercial code.

Answer (score 1):

To do this using variable-length arrays (which you already are using, and which were a part of C 1999 but are optional in C 2011), make two changes. Inside the function `input_array`, change the `malloc` statement from:

```
int *arr=malloc((*size_x)*(*size_y)*sizeof(int));
```

to:

```
int (*arr)[*size_y] = malloc(*size_x * sizeof *arr);
```

This defines `arr` to be a pointer to an array of `*size_y` `int`, so it acts like an array of arrays, which is the two-dimensional array you wanted.

Second, since `arr` is a pointer to an array of `int`, you should not return it as an `int *`, so the return type must be changed. Unfortunately, you cannot declare the return type in advance since you do not know the second dimension of the array at compile time. So you must return it in the same form `malloc` gives it to you, a `void *`:

```
void *input_array(int *size_x, int *size_y)
```

Then the caller of `input_array` must cast it to a pointer of the appropriate type:

```
void *temporary = *input_array(&size_x, &size_y);
if (!temporary) HandleError;
int (*array)[size_y] = temporary;
```

There are two other ways to handle two-dimensional arrays.

One is to allocate the space as a one-dimensional array of `int` (or other element) and use your own arithmetic to convert two-dimensional indices into one-dimension (mapping row `i` and column `j` to element `i*NumberOfColumns + j`). You might write small functions or preprocessor macros to make the indexing look a little nicer. This is essentially the same thing the compiler does when you use variable-length arrays, but it is usable in compilers that do not support variable-length arrays.

Another method often suggested on Stack Overflow is to create an array of pointers and initialize them to point to rows of the array. So, if `p` is a pointer to the array of pointers, then `p[i]` is one of the pointers (so it points to a row of the array), and `p[i][j]` is an element in that row. This is generally a bad solution, for several reasons. One, it consumes more space. Two, it requires an extra memory load (to get the second pointer). Three, it interferes with optimization by the compiler.

On the latter point, when you have a variable-length array or a one-dimensional array with manually calculated indices, the compiler can see that `a[i][j]` and `a[i+1][j]` refer to different elements, so it can optimize operations on these elements to execute in parallel. In the pointer method, `a[i]` and `a[i+1]` are pointers to rows, and the compiler generally cannot know whether they point to the same row or to overlapping rows, and this prevents it from optimization uses of `a[i][j]` and `a[i+1][j]`.

Answer (score 0):

First the error you're getting: you have to explicitly convert the void* type from malloc to int*:

```
int *arr= (int*) malloc((*size_x)*(*size_y)*sizeof(int));
```

Second, if you allocate just a block of RAM, you would have to calculate the array index for yourself.  For example:

```
arr[y*(*size_x)+x] = 123;
```

So you have to allocate an array for (*size_x) number of `int*` pointers, and then you have to allocate (*size_x) number of separate `int` arrays with size of (*size_y) each and store  their pointers into the `int*` array. Then you could use the `arr[x][y]` notation.

Comment: C does not require casting to convert `void *` to `int *` in an assignment. The error in the `scanf` line occurs because, when `arr` is declared as `int *`, the expression `arr[i]` is an `int`, not a pointer, and therefore `arr[i][j]` is incorrect, since the second subscript operator requires a pointer, not an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an array of pointers each assigned an array of integers.

```
int** makeTable(int size_x, int size_y){
    int z;
    int** table;
    /* get an array of pointers of length x */
    table = malloc(sizeof(int*) * size_x);
    for(z = 0; z < size_x; z++){
        /* call calloc to zero out an array */
        table[z] = calloc(sizeof(int), size_y);
    }
    return table;
}
```

then you can use `table[i][j]`